# How to get rid of excessive update queries generated by Doctrine MongoDB ODM?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I have following Documents:
Order with EmbedMany Orderlines
Orderline with EmbedOne Product

I have an existing Order where I want to add a new Orderline, but I'm getting two new Orderlines added when I fetch an existing Order and add new Orderline to it.

Code from my controller:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();

// Get the session id for current user
$sessionId = $this->get('session')->getId();

// Fetch an existing order
$order = $dm->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Order')
    ->findOneBy(array('session_id' => $sessionId));

// Create a new product
$product = new Product();
$product->setTitle('Product title');

// Create an orderline
$orderline = new Orderline();
$orderline->setProduct($product);
$orderline->setQuantity(1);

// Add newly created orderline to the order
$order->addOrderlines($orderline);

$dm->persist($orderline);
$dm->flush();
```

MongoDB query generated by Doctrine:

```
use test_database;
db.Order.find({ "session_id": "ransbtpa63cdbp5vp7fqs2pma5" });
db.Product.insert({ "00000000723450f000000000b20415bf": { "_id":      ObjectId("50fc67348e97f4d119000002"), "title": "Product title" } });
db.Orderline.insert({ "000000007234500d00000000b20415bf": { "_id": ObjectId("50fc67348e97f4d119000003"), "product": { "_id": ObjectId("50fc67348e97f4d119000002"), "title": "Product title" }, "quantity": 1 } });
db.Order.update({ "_id": ObjectId("50fc62a18e97f44f1d000002") }, { "$set": { "orderlines.5.product.title": "Product title", "orderlines.5.quantity": 1 } });
db.Order.update({ "_id": ObjectId("50fc62a18e97f44f1d000002") }, { "$pushAll": { "orderlines": [ { "_id": ObjectId("50fc67348e97f4d119000003"), "product": { "_id": ObjectId("50fc67348e97f4d119000002"), "title": "Product title" }, "quantity": 1 } ] } });
```

And order document from MongoDB (Orderlines 1 and 2 where added by the query):

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 50fc62a18e97f44f1d000002
)
[orderlines] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [_id] => MongoId Object (
            [$id] => 50fc62a18e97f44f1d000001
        )
        [product] => Array (
            [_id] => MongoId Object (
                [$id] => 50fc62a18e97f44f1d000000
            )
            [title] => Product title
        )
        [quantity] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [product] => Array (
            [title] => Product title
        )
        [quantity] => 1
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [_id] => MongoId Object (
            [$id] => 50fc62d08e97f4f41d000002
        )
        [product] => Array (
            [_id] => MongoId Object (
                [$id] => 50fc62d08e97f4f41d000001
            )
            [title] => Product title
        )
        [quantity] => 1
    )
)
[session_id] => ransbtpa63cdbp5vp7fqs2pma5
```

I think the problem is caused by the first db.Order.insert query with $set, followed by $pushAll.
How can I get rid of that excessive query and why is Doctrine generating it?

Comment: The queries displayed match what you do in the PHP code, I am unsure what the problem is. If you want less queries to be run I suggest you change how your application is run

Comment: Problem is that every time the posted controller code is run, two orderlines are created to the order document in MongoDB. I would need it to create only one.

Comment: Instead of adding to the order, try just setting the `order` from `orderline` by using `$orderline->setOrder($order)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was missing EmbeddedDocument annotation in the Orderline document and adding that fixed the problem.

```
/**
* @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
*/
class Orderline
{
...
```

Comment: Please accept your answer, so your question won't show up in "questions with unaccepted answers"... thanks!